# how to install PL/SQL Developer on centos

Tags: installation, centos-7, plsql-developer

Can we install and run PL/SQL Developer on CentOS 7 server? I couldn't find installation documents anywhere. If the installation is possible can someone guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you were referring to PL/SQL Developer it is [only supported on windows](https://www.componentsource.com/product/pl-sql-developer/compatibilities)

> PL/SQL Developer will run on Windows XP, 2003, Vista, Windows 7,
>   Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

If you were talking about Oracle SQL developer it [is supported on](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/sqldev-relnotes-41-2372786.html)

> Oracle SQL Developer 4.1 is available for Windows 7,8,10 and Windows
>   Server 2008/2012, Linux or Mac OS X

You need to install Java version 1.8 and the SQL Developer executable. From [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-linux-install-1932164.html)

- Ensure you have a JDK installed, if not, download here
- Download SQL Developer
- rpm -Uhv sqldeveloper--1.noarch.rpm
- cd sqldeveloper - sqldeveloper